# how to handle FormatException in ServiceStack 3.9.71

Tags: servicestack

I have a request DTO with the route:

`[Route("/user/address/{Id}", "GET")]`

the `Id` is `int`

When I use this URL http://my_domain/user/address/abc, I get this exception:

```
[FormatException]: .....
[SerializationException]......
[RequestBindingException].....
```

I defined `CustomHttpHandlers` in my code, but cannot get it to work.

How can I handle this exception?

Comment: Please provide the DTO definition as well as the signature of the service method using the DTO.

Comment: If Id is an int, why do you pass "abc" ?